# How can I design my data warehouse to deal with a late arriving data source?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse, columnstore

Hi I'm working on a MS SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition data warehouse for a customer and have hit upon a challenge that I'm looking for advice on.

I have a reasonably large fact table holding retail till transactions (About 2.5 million rows per day with 3 years of history). The majority of the fact table is pulled from a single source - the till system. So we currently have an ETL process loading data from this system, modelling it to look up surrogate keys etc and loading into a fact table every hour. The table has a clustered columnstore index to ensure good performance in the BI tool.

Now the customer has a loyalty app system they want to integrate. This system sends us data on a daily CSV extract. The extract holds details of app transactions and associated offers taken through the app and contains a common transaction ID that matches the one held already in our fact table.

If these sources arrived together, I would model a new dimension table - DimAppOffer or similar and use the two sources to look up which offers had been associated with each transaction and have a AppOfferKey on the fact table. But since this CSV file only arrives once per day and transactions are loaded every hour, all of the associated transactions already exist in the fact table by the time I get the data from the loyalty app.

How do you think I should handle this in the ETL? I don't particularly want to run a large update against a clustered columnstore index if I can avoid it, but I can't see another way around it? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't particularly want to run a large update against a clustered columnstore index if I can avoid it, but I can't see another way around it?

You can either load the facts with a null or "missing member" in the dimension key, or add a new dimension member during ETL with null/unknown non-key attributes and link the fact to that, as suggested here: [Late Arriving Dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/late-arriving-dimension/).

If you create a the new dimension member when the fact arrives, you only have to update the dimension when the data arrives.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't have the dimensional business key until the data arrives. The dimension would not be based on the transaction no, but on an OfferID associated with the transaction number in the CSV file. So I can't use the late arriving dimension advice in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I prefer to create a second factless fact table with transaction id and the app offer details (similar to your AppOffer dimension but just use the transaction id as the key)

Then you can create a view for your main fact and this new table using LEFT join for analytics.

Comment: Does that have any performance concerns though? It would essentially mean creating a snowflake schema rather than a star wouldn't it?

Comment: Star schema does not mean good performance because you will need to join those dimension tables. You an also skip the view, just use the the fact tables

Comment: So you're saying, fact table to factless fact table to dimension as a data model? That could work as long as the query performance doesn't degrade too much.